# Nonisomorphic Groups with the Same Order and Exponent

Tags: finite-groups, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups

I am trying to find two nonisomorphic finite abelian groups with the same order and exponent. I've tried solving this problem for a fews days, but I have had no luck. I tried looking for pairs of such groups of the form $\Bbb{Z}_{mn}$ and $\Bbb{Z}_m \oplus \Bbb{Z}_n$. I've tried searching for examples, but when it comes to numeracy, I am severely lacking.  But I fairly convinced that no such pair constitutes an example.

If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then the two groups are actually isomorphic, so this case is relatively uninteresting. Hence, suppose that $m < n$ are not relatively prime, and let $d$ be their GCD. Under this case, there are million subcases and considered for either finding an example or showing no such example exists (e.g., if one could show that $nd < mn$ and $m | nd$, then I believe this would show no such example exists, etc.)

Comment: You will need more than two summands: ${\mathbb Z}_4\oplus{\mathbb Z}_4$ and ${\mathbb Z}_4\oplus{\mathbb Z}_2\oplus{\mathbb Z}_2$ will be an example.

Comment: There are lots of examples of pairs of groups with the property you want (lulu mentioned one such pair), but you won't find any of type $C_{mn}$, $C_m \times C_n$ with $\gcd(m,n)>1$.

Comment: @the_fox Ah, interesting. So how do we show that no such pair constitutes an example? I couldn't figure this out.

Comment: The exponent of $C_{mn}$ is $mn$. What is the exponent of $C_m \times C_n$? It's going to be $\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$, right? But $\gcd(m,n) \cdot \mathrm{lcm}(m,n) = mn$. Can you finish it?

Comment: @the_fox ...$lcm(m,n) < gcd(m,n) \cdot lcm(m,n) = mn$, because $gcd(m,n) > 1$ (strictly inequality). Is this right?

Comment: Yes. So if $\gcd(m,n)>1$ those two exponents can't be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf{V}=\{(1),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$ be the four-group, and let $\Gamma_{4}=\langle i\rangle=\{1,i,-1,-i\}$ be the multiplicative cyclic group of fourth roots of unity, where $i^{2}=-1.$ Then these are the two abelian groups with the same order. We will see they are not isomorphic.

If there were an isomorphism $f:\mathbf{V}\rightarrow\Gamma_{4},$ then surjectivity of $f$ would provide some $x\in\mathbf{V}$ with $i=f(x).$ But $x^{2}=(1)$ for all $x\in\mathbf{V},$ so that$$i^{2}=f(x)^{2}=f(x^{2})=f((1))=1,$$contradicting $i^{2}=-1.$ Therefore, $\mathbf{V}$ and $\Gamma_{4}$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: $V$ has exponent two, and $\langle i\rangle$ has exponent four, so this does not work.

Comment: I’m sorry that I ignored it …but indeed I don’t know how to solve this problem if it’s required the same exponent.